# Java scripts are blocked in Chrome

Tags: javascript

In my application (VB.net) java Script are not being execute but in IE same is working fine.Any help to fix it..??
Thanks in advance.
Showing error on Developer tool
captureEvents() is deprecated. This method doesn't do anything.
releaseEvents() is deprecated. This method doesn't do anything.

Comment: It's hard to tell you what to do with no code to go by. But you seem to have identified your issues, which means you could google those items such as [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=captureevents+deprecated&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: I added IE Tab in chrome & FireFox, and its working fine. Now, I want to check whether IE TAB plugin is already added or not in Browser at run time on page load. My application is in VB.net. What to do..??